# simpleDialog plugin won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

For my project I need to popup an image when i push a button. 
I am trying to use the SimpleDialog plugin, which you can see over [here](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/index.html).
I am doing this in my HTML

```
<p>This shows standard, default popup only mode.</p>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                $(document).delegate('#popupbut', 'click', function() {
                    $('<div>').simpledialog2({
                        mode: 'blank',
                        headerText: 'Some Stuff',
                        headerClose: true,
                        blankContent : 
                            "<ul data-role='listview'><li>Some</li><li>List</li><li>Items</li></ul>"+
                            "<a rel='close' data-role='button' href='#'>Close</a>"
                    })
                });
            </script>
            <a href="#" id="popupbut" data-role="button">Open Dialog</a>
```

I have included the JS and CSS properly. But for some reason it won't work.
Does anybody have an idea? Or an other alternative for the SimpleDialog plugin?

Kind Regards

------**EDIT** -------
OK I got it to work with the example above.
But now I only want to show an image. So I do this in my script.

```
    $(document).delegate('#opendialog', 'click', function() {
                    // NOTE: The selector can be whatever you like, so long as it is an HTML element.
                    //  If you prefer, it can be a member of the current page, or an anonymous div
                    //       like shown.
                          $('<div>').simpledialog2({
                        mode: 'blank',
                            headerText: 'Some Stuff',
                            headerClose: true,
                          blankContent : 
                            "<img src="images/schema.jpg" alt="schema" width="100" height="100" />"


 })
            })
```

But this wont work. Anybody can help?

Comment: Have you checked it via firebug for errors?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't give any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my post, this should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).delegate('#opendialog', 'click', function() {
  $('<div>').simpledialog2({
    mode: 'blank',
    headerText: 'Some Stuff',
    headerClose: true,
    dialogAllow: true,
    dialogForce: true,
    blankContent : 
      "<img src=\"images/schema.jpg\" alt=\"schema\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" />"+
      "<a rel='close' data-role='button' href='#'>Close</a>"
  })
})
</script>

<a href="#" id="opendialog" data-role="button">Open Dialog</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok this works, but now I have a problem with putting an image in this simple dialog. I've edited my question

Comment: Like what ? When I only put "<p>test dialog  </p>" in the blankcontent it works.

Comment: Never mind I read your post wrong. I updated my post, the posted code should work.